# PHP Contact form will only send one time

Tags: php, forms, contacts

First, I am not a web designer - I am a graphic designer, so I am no PHP expert.

Here is my issue: I have a simple contact form I built for a webpage. This form has multiple recipients based on the topic chosen in the first form selection. This form appears on the site correctly, works and sends - but only ONCE. It will only send - one time - after i reload a new .php file to my server. Ive gone to different computers, used different IPs as i read it may be a cookie issue (which is not in my code) and still only ever sends one time. I've researched and Im starting to see only the same answers, so thought I would ask. I have removed unwanted spaces as was recommended, no help. I tried adding a false statement in regards to the submit button(like I said no php pro, excuse my verbiage), no help. I have changed the "From" to an @mywebsite type of entry instead of something like "Website User," as recommended for validation, no luck. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

My PHP file:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$yourEmail = $_POST['yourEmail'];
$businessName = $_POST['businessName'];
$businessType = $_POST['businessType'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$stateProvince = $_POST['stateProvince'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$zipPostalcode = $_POST['zipPostalcode'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$contactPref = $_POST['contactPref'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

switch ($sendTo)
{
case "aftermarketCustomerservice":
$sendTo="email1@ipa.net";
break;

case "technicalAssistance":
$sendTo="email2@ipa.net";
break;

case "aftermarketSales":
$sendTo="email3@ipa.net";
break;

case "performanceProducts":
$sendTo="email4@ipa.net";
break;

case "oemSales":
$sendTo="email5@ipa.net";
break;

case "exportSales":
$sendTo="email6@ipa.net";
break;

case "generalFeedback":
$sendTo="email7@ipa.net";
break;

default:
$sendTo="email8@ipa.net";
}

$subject="Website Contact Form";
$message="From: $name  \r \n Reply to: $yourEmail  \r \n Message: $message \r \n Business Name:         
$businessName \r \n Business Type: $businessType \r \n Address: $address, $city, $stateProvince, 
$zipPostalcode,$country \r \n Phone: $phone \r \n Fax: $fax \r \n Contact Preference: 
$contactPref ";

$send=mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, "From: websiteuser@website.com");

$todayis=date("l, F j, Y");
echo "Email succesfully sent to Company Name on $todayis";

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder ?

Comment: Please note that the `switch-case` block defines only one sendto address. So this script should send email only once to the $sendTo address.

Comment: if you are not receiving any errors then it most likely will be a server configuration issue.

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($send);` after sending e-mail ?

Comment: @Fallen as far as i understood the question, the email is only sent once overall. that it only goes out to one of the addresses is intended i think.

Comment: @VladPreda, Yes and receiving no junk mail

Comment: @Fallen, Yes I only want it to send to one email at a time. But overall the form only works ONE time period. I have to delete the .php from GoDaddy and reload it to get another email to go through

Comment: where does the "sendTo" variable get initialized?

Comment: @northkildonan, I am seeing the "Email successfully sent to blah blah" message after I click the submit button - is that where I should be seeing an error message if one was happening?

Comment: @Fallen, Meaning how is the specific email chosen?

Comment: <select id="sendTo" name="sendTo">
  <option id="pleaseSelectcategory1" value="pleaseSelectcategory1">Please Select Category</option>
  <option id="aftermarketCustomerservice" value="aftermarketCustomerservice">Aftermarket Customer Service</option>
  <option id="technicalAssistance" value="technicalAssistance">Technical Assistance</option>
                <option id="aftermarketSales" value="aftermarketSales">Aftermarket Sales</option>

Comment: @KJones well, you'll receive this text everytime, because it's just printed out by PHP no matter what. try to replace the line: `echo "Email succesfully sent to Company Name on $todayis";` with `if($send){ echo "Email succesfully sent to Company Name on $todayis"; } else { echo "Error sending the Email";}`

Comment: in your code `switch ($sendTo)`, I can't see this $sendTo getting initiallized. may be you need to put `$sendTo = $_POST['sendTo']` ?

Comment: Thats a portion of the drop down which defines which email the form is sent to. Sorry it looks a mess.

Comment: Ive added both bits of code and not getting anything. I added the $sendTo = $_POST['sendTo'] after my $message = $_POST['message'];   Any reason this would be incorrect?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, I am honestly not sure on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is change those lines:

```
$send=mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, "From: websiteuser@website.com");

$todayis=date("l, F j, Y");
echo "Email succesfully sent to Company Name on $todayis";
```

into:

```
$send=mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, "From: websiteuser@website.com");

if ($send) {
  $todayis=date("l, F j, Y");
  echo "Email succesfully sent to Company Name on $todayis";
}
else {
  echo "Email couldn't be sent";
}
```

and tell us what's the result.

You could also change:

```
<?php
```

into

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to make sure any other errors don't appear. Of course those 2 lines about displaying errors you should remove when your application will be on production server.

Comment: Ok I got the "Email succesfully sent to Company Name on Friday, July 25, 2014" yet no email. I spoke with GoDaddy - She said due to these not being "common" emails such as @ hotmail or @ yahoo, they have to be added. This has been done - I guess ill be retesting in about 2 hours and hope this is the issue. She was able to get a test email to me by way of the .php file to my hotmail account no problem.

Comment: I could also try using dedicated PHP mail library as for instance PHP Mailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer and then you can use SMTP what is more reliable method to send emails.

Comment: Ok GoDaddy has not solved my problem. Yet again I sent 4 forms and only received the first. Is this maybe a submit button issue? As GoDaddy was able to get out multiple emails just by using the PHP.

<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>

Comment: @KJones rather not, if you send email it's being send and it should work. However there might be also some server restrictions (for example daily limit or hour limit). You should try with this library I mentioned using SMTP and maybe then it will work better.

Comment: Hmm I see, though I really do appreciate the suggestion, I wasn't even sure which file to download. Then at that point where I would go from there. As I said I am far from a developer, just got handed the project as I am the only one in the office who could muster together a website. 

An UPDATE to my issue - i have changed the receiving email to a hotmail and it sends instantly and sends over and over no problem. So I guess the issue is the company's email I am using and just need to get that set up correctly somehow so it does not reject my form.